# Spring Integration DSL Error Handler Thread ID

Tags: java, error-handling, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Currently I am keeping track of active threads that in process due to not letting system shutdown until I do not have any procesing threads

For example

```
package com.example.demo.flow;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.*;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.channel.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.integration.file.dsl.Files;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * Created by on 03/01/2020.
 */
@Component
@Slf4j
public class TestFlow {

    @Bean
    public StandardIntegrationFlow errorChannelHandler() {

        return IntegrationFlows.from("testChannel")
                .handle(o -> {

                    log.info("Handling error....{}", o);
                }).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow testFile() {


        IntegrationFlowBuilder testChannel = IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("d:/input-files/")),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000L).maxMessagesPerPoll(5)
                        .errorChannel("testChannel")))
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)))
                .transform(o -> {

                    throw new RuntimeException("Failing on purpose");

                }).handle(o -> {
                });

        return testChannel.get();


    }


}
```

I have enabled multiple file for integration flow but in Error Handler the thread is different
How can I know which thread did it come from?

Is there anyway I can find out as this is very critical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your current configuration the `testChannel` is a `DrectChannel`, so whatever you send to it is going to be processed on a thread your send from.
Therefore the `Thread.currentThread()` is enough for your to determine it.

For more general solution consider to have a `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` as a bean with the `ChannelUtils.MESSAGE_PUBLISHING_ERROR_HANDLER_BEAN_NAME` to override a default one. This `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` can be supplied with a custom `ErrorMessageStrategy`. There, when you create an `ErrorMessage`, you can add a custom header with the same `Thread.currentThread()` info to carry onto that error channel processing even if it is done in a separate thread.

You also could just throw an exception with that info, too, instead!

Comment: Thread.currentThread() work only if there was a single thread but lets say i receieved two files at a time in error channel now the thread id is different 
For example thread-1 and thread-2 started the thread in actual but in error channel it i ssomething thread-3 i don't know

Comment: Well, you probably is confused a bit that the poller is done on its own scheduled thread and then you shift the work to an `ExecutorChannel`. But still your conclusion about `Thread.currentThread()` is not clear. You may use `enrichHeaders()` just before your executor channel (or after) to add the current thread info into headers. And that one is going to be curried to the error handler anyway.

Comment: I have tried that it doesn't propogage the current thread

Comment: Show, please, in your question how you have it tried?

Comment: I think I must have mistaken in my implemention. You are right, Thread.currentThread() does look like the same. I'll try more and get back. Thanks for so immeditate response

Comment: I can cofirm its workign as you mentinoed its indeed passing the same THREAD.